# Prisma cannot connect fields, type uncompatible

Tags: postgresql, next.js, prisma

I'm currently using Next JS with Prisma (PostgreSQL). I've been trying to create a new record in a table while also connecting a record from another table – however, I'm getting the following error:

```
Type '{ userId: string; user: { connect: { id: string; }; }; year: number; newGoals: any; }' is not assignable to type '(Without<UserEvaluationCreateInput, UserEvaluationUncheckedCreateInput> & UserEvaluationUncheckedCreateInput) | (Without<...> & UserEvaluationCreateInput)'.
  Types of property 'user' are incompatible.
    Type '{ connect: { id: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(2693, 5): The expected type comes from property 'data' which is declared here on type '{ select?: UserEvaluationSelect<DefaultArgs> | null | und
```

Here is the database schema file:

```
model User {
  id String @id
  pos String
  role String
  evaluation UserEvaluation?
}

model UserEvaluation {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId String @unique
  year Int
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
  newGoals String 
}
```

And here is the function that creates and connects the fields:

```
await prismadb.userEvaluation.create({
    data: { 
        userId: userId, 
        user: { connect: { id: userId }},
        year: 20232, 
        newGoals: goal 
    }
})
```

Thanks!